# create inputfield with span on the right side

Tags: html, css

**First: I dont use bootstrap, I want to build this, without bootstrap.**

I want to create this

[image]

,but I dont know how to handle the span on the right side of the input field. Here is my try.

```css
.input_register{
 padding: 5px;
 border: 2px solid green;
}

.input_register:hover{
 border: 2px solid #151A22;
}

.input_register:focus{
 border: 2px solid #151A22;
}

.register_span{
 background-color: red;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 2px solid #151A22;
    border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="input_group">
  <input class="input_register" type="text"/><span class="register_span">D</span>
</div>
```

Why is the span higher as the inputfield?

Comment: nvm I got bootply working and fixed the issue. see my answer below!

Comment: Are you trying to do this _without_ bootstrap?

Comment: @Name updated my answer with a jsfiddle too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### display: inline-block;

`inline-block` displays similar characteristics as an inline element while being able to alter the sizing like a block element.

Setting `line-height: 1em` sets the height of the `containing block` equal to the size of the font. In this case I've used `line-height: 1.5em` to give it some extra space.

Also, vertical padding on these elements yields unexpected results, using line-height instead gives a more consistent appearance.

```css
.input_register,
.register_span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12pt;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

.input_register{
    border: 2px solid green;
}

.input_register:hover{
    border: 2px solid #151A22;
}

.input_register:focus{
    border: 2px solid #151A22;
}

.register_span{
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid #151A22;
    border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="input_group">
  <input class="input_register" type="text"/><span class="register_span">D</span>
</div>
```